# Speed up removing stopwords from huge csv-file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, stop-words

Is there a better (faster) way to remove stopwords from a csv file?

Here is the simple code, and over an hour later I am still waiting for the results (so I don't even know if it's actually working):

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import csv
import codecs

f = codecs.open("agenericcsvfile.csv","r","utf-8")
readit = f.read()
f.close()

filtered = [w for w in readit if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
```

The csv-file has 50.000 rows and a total of ~15 million words. Why does it take so long? Sadly, this is only a subcorpora. I will have to do this with over 1 million rows and over 300 million words. So is there a way to speed things up? Or a more elegant code?

CSV-file sample:

```
1 text,sentiment
2 Loosely based on The Decameron, Jeff Baena's subversive film takes us behind the walls of a 13th century convent and squarely in the midst of a trio of lustful sisters, Alessandra (Alison Brie), Fernanda (Aubrey Plaza), and Ginerva (Kate Micucci) who are "beguiled" by a new handyman, Massetto (Dave Franco). He is posing as a deaf [...] and it is coming undone from all of these farcical complications.,3
3 One might recommend this film to the most liberally-minded of individuals, but even that is questionable as [...] But if you are one of the ribald loving few, who likes their raunchy hi-jinks with a satirical sting, this is your kinda movie. For me, the satire was lost.,5
4 [...]
[...]
50.000 The movie is [...] tht is what I ahve to say.,9
```

The desired output would be the same csv-file without the stop-words.

Comment: Which Python version is this - can you add the appropriate tag?

Comment: Also please add a meaningful sample of the input CSV and the desired output for that sample.

Comment: BTW, shouldn't the string in the CSV be quoted? Otherwise, how to distinguish `,` in text from `,` separating text and sentiment? Also, `readit` seems to be just one string holding all the chars in the file, not a list of words. (You import, but never use the `csv` module.)

Comment: @tobias_k I tried, but it would be a string without line breaks? Is there a way to do it properly?

Answer (score 4):

The first obvious optimization would be to 1/ avoid calling `stopwords.words()` in each iteration and 2/ make it a `set` (`set` lookup is O(1) where `list` lookup is O(N)):

```
words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
filtered = [w for w in readit if not w in words]
```

but this will not yield the expected results since `readit` is a string so you are actually iterating on individual characters, not words. You need to tokenize your string before, [as explained here][1]:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
readit = word_tokenize(readit)
# now readit is a proper list of words...
filtered = [w for w in readit if not w in words]
```

but now you've lost all the csv newlines, so you cannot properly rebuild it... And you might have some issues with quoting too if there's any quoting in your csv. So actually you may want to properly parse your source with a `csv.reader` and clean up your data field by field, row by row, which will of course add quite some overhead. Well, if your goal is to rebuild the csv without the stopwords, that is (else you may not care that much).

Anwyay: if you have a really huge corpus to cleanup and need performances, the next step is really parallelization: split the source data in parts, send each part to a distinct process (one per processor/core is a good start), possibly distributed over many computers, and collect the result. This pattern is known as "map reduce" and their are a couple Python implementations already.

Comment: Uff, my code has a lot more flaws than a thought. I will have to rethink the whole thing. I don't thin I understand how to not lose the csv delimeters. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @TAN-C-F-OK sorry I accidentally submitted my answer before it was ready. You actually won't loose the punctuation (I just tested with nltk) but csv formats can be tricky and just tokenizing the whole data at once will probably not work (at least not in a way that would allow rebuilding the csv). cf my edited answer for more details.

Comment: Would it be better/easier/faster to remove the stopwords before the corpus is a giant csv file? I got every row in a single text-file (ergo 50K txt-files). The thing is, that I did not find a way to do it with all the txt-files (only one file at a time)

Comment: Working on a lot of small files will indeed avoid the csv formatting issues. Also it makes parallelisation much easier. All you have to do is to replace the hardcoded file path with a parameter then launch N parallel process to process your files (this part can be written as another script).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the stop words returned by NLTK are a `list`, thus having O(n) lookup. Convert the list to a `set` first, then it will be much faster.

```
>>> some_word = "aren't"
>>> stop = stopwords.words('english')
>>> type(stop)
list
>>> %timeit some_word in stop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.3 µs per loop

>>> stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
>>> %timeit some_word in stop
10000000 loops, best of 3: 43.8 ns per loop
```

However, while this should solve the performanc problem, it seems like your code is not doing what you expect it to do in the first place. `readit` is a single string holding the content of the entire file, thus you are iterating characters and not words. You import the `csv` module, but you never use it. Also, the strings in your `csv` file should be quoted, otherwise it will split at *all* `,`, not just at the last one. If you can not change the csv file, it might be easier to use `str.rsplit` though.

```
texts = [line.rsplit(",", 1)[0] for line in readit.splitlines()]
filtered = [[w for w in text.split() if w.lower() not in stopwords_set]
            for text in texts]
```